# Does pepsin enzyme digest other enzymes like other pepsin molecules

Tags: digestive-system

Pepsin digests proteins, as we know, but can it digest other enzymes that are actually made up of proteins, like digesting other pepsin molecules?

Answer (score 2):

Pepsin **does** cleave itself [(Ingram, 1951)](https://www.nature.com/articles/167083a0) - this is termed autolysis. Pepsin (and other proteases) act on proteins with the right amino acid sequences. Pepsin prefers to cleave at phenylalanine, tryptophan or tyrosine residues (Lehninger, A. Principles of Biochemistry).

* Pepsin can also cleave inactive 'zymogen' enzymes to activate them. One of these zymogens is pepsinogen (an inactive form of pepsin itself). So you *could* argue that pepsin is cleaving itself here but I personally wouldn't, since pepsinogen isn't really pepsin.

Comment: Confusingly, pepsin *does* cleave itself - or, rather pepsinogen does to make pepsin (autocatalysis). Hmm, it also does autolysis, so I'm not sure your answer is correct ...

Comment: @gilleain I've added a note about it. I was initially going to talk about zymogens but I felt that it would be muddying the answer. Personally I'd say pepsin and pepsinogen are different things, plus (to my mind) the question is asking whether a solution of purified pepsin will eventually eat itself.

Comment: Jam, indeed - that's autolysis! Apparently, you should store pepsin at a low temperature to stop it eating itself

Comment: @gilleain Well I'll be! Never realised it did eat itself! Thanks for letting me know

Comment: Regarding your note on terminology: (1) digestion is common parlance for proteases and nucleases. (2) not all enzymes are proteins.

Comment: @canadianer Thanks for the notes - my mistake on both parts.